# Angular js ng-repeat and directives

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a list of items that can be starred. The buttons to archive, delete and star pop up on hover. However, if the item is starred, the star does not fade out but remains visible.  [image]

I have created a directive 'list' to handle the effect.

```
app.directive "list",() ->
    restrict: 'A'
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
        selected = false
        element.on 'mouseenter', ->
            $ element.find(".sub-menu > label, .sub-menu > a").show()
        element.on 'mouseleave', ->
            if attrs['list'] is "true"
                $ element.find(".sub-menu > .ng-archive, .sub-menu > a").hide()
            else
                $ element.find(".sub-menu > label, .sub-menu > a").hide()

        element.on 'click', ->
            selected =! selected
            if selected then element.addClass 'list-selected' else element.removeClass 'list-selected'
            console.log scope

            # I want to execute the following statement when initializing
        if attrs['list'] is "true"
            $ element.find(".sub-menu > .ng-archive, .sub-menu > a").hide()
        else
            $ element.find(".sub-menu > label, .sub-menu > a").hide()
```

The actual li element

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" list="{{item.starred}}">
```

The problem is that, if an item is starred, the red star does not show up until I hover over the element rather than at initialization of the data itself. After that, everything works fine.

It appears that the list attribute does not get the value from `{{item.starred}}` at initialization. When i output the value to the console, I got `undefined`. Only when I hover over the elements, the list attribute is properly assigned with the value from `{{item.starred}}`

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the `item.starred` value from a server? if so, then getting `undefined` is expected, because the directive is initailized before the data returned from server.

I would suggest to use CSS to show the Red star instead of using javascript `hide` and `show` event. Alternatively, you can use angular `watch` to observe the change of the `Item` value and run the javascript code.